# intent not working in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to start new activity using an intent but it never works.

**two activities**

1. MainActivity.java
2. Play.java

**two layouts**

1. activity_main.xml
2. layoutplay.xml

it shows  `THE APPLICATION HAS STOPPED UNEXPECTEDLY`
where is the mistake?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.xxx;



import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Typeface t= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");

    TextView tv1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv1.setTypeface(t);
    tv1.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getId()==R.id.textView1){

        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Play.class);

        MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);

    }
       }    
}
```

---

**Play.java**

```
package com.example.xxx;

import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;


    public class Play extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutplay);
}  
   }
```

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:src="@drawable/bouncemenuback" 
   android:contentDescription="@string/menuback"  />

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       style="@style/my"
       android:text="@string/Play"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     </RelativeLayout>
```

**layoutplay.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Play" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

**xxx.manifest**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="9" />

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.xxx.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.xxx.Play"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_play" >
         />

    </activity>
   </application>

 </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

try by removing unused `/>` inside  `<activity  android:name="com.example.xxx.Play" ..... >  />  </activity>`  in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

so your code should be :

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.xxx.Play"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_play" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your manifest code with this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="9" />

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.xxx.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.xxx.Play"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PLAY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

 </manifest>
```

Hope this helps :)